# Playable audio file

Tags: html, audio

I want to have users be able to click a link to play audio on my website, but I don't want there to be an actual 'file', I just wanted to access it from external Cloud storage. Is there a way to make a link play an audio file? I do not want to go to an actual file. I simply want to play that audio in the "background" of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

> `<embed name="yoursong" src="/music/yoursong.mp3" loop="true" hidden="false" autostart="false">`